# Robot Framework makes two instances from the class instead of one

Tags: python, import, robotframework

I have a python class:

```
from robot.api import logger
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        logger.info('initialized', also_console=True)

    def print_arg1(self):
        print self.arg1

    def print_arg2(self):
        print self.arg2
```

I have wrote a keyword file named "CommonKeywords.robot":

```
*** Settings ***
Library     ../Libs/TestClass.py     arg1   arg2        WITH NAME    class1

*** Keywords ***
print arg1 class1
    class1.print_arg1

print arg2 class1
    class1.print_arg2
```

And my scenario file is "scenario.robot":

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../Keywords/CommonKeywords.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Test Prints
    print arg1 class1
```

This is my project structure:

```
Test
---- Keywords
     ---- CommonKeywords.robot
---- Scenarios
     ---- scenario.robot
---- Libs
     ---- TestClass.py
```

I change directory to the `Test/Scenarios` and type `pybot scenario.robot` in the command line. The script prints two `initialized` which means it had been initialized the object twice:

[image]

What is the problem??

I changed my class this way:

```
from robot.api import logger
class TestClass(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        logger.info('initialized', also_console=True)

    def print_arg1(self):
        print self.arg1

    def print_arg2(self):
        print self.arg2
```

This is what I wanted and I have got after applying Bryan's answer:

[image]

Comment: I don't reproduce your issue. Where do you get "initialized" printed? I don't even get it once.

Comment: @LaurentBristiel, I have added some details. BTW, Bryan's answer was great! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the scope of your library.

From the [Robot Framework User's Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope) (emphasis mine):

> Robot Framework attempts to keep test cases independent from each
>   other: *by default, it creates new instances of test libraries for*
>   *every test case*. However, this behavior is not always desirable,
>   because sometimes test cases should be able to share a common state.
>   Additionally, all libraries do not have a state and creating new
>   instances of them is simply not needed.

If you want to have the class created once per test suite, you can set the scope like this:

```
class TestClass(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...
```

If you want the class instantiated just once for the life of the entire test run you can set `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE` to `'GLOBAL'`.

Comment: Thank you, the `GLOBAL` option has solved my problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley what if I require one suite to have a single instance across all tests, and another suite to have independent instances for each test? In your answer you have set a robot variable inside the python class. However, I want to know if I can set this inside my test suite (.robot) file.