# Robot Framework: Multiple Resource-Files accessing the same Library

Tags: robotframework

Hello to all RobotFramework users

## Problem

We have many keywords at different levels of abstraction and are looking for a simple way to import them while maintaining support for autocompletion etc. in IDEs.

The inheritance could look as follows:

```
   /---------------------> basic_keywords.robot <---\
  /                             ^                    \
 /                              |                    |
 |  advanced_keywords_1.robot --/            advanced_keywords_2.robot
 |            ^
 |            |
more_advanced_keywords_1.robot
```

## Proposal 1: Import all keywords in `all_keywords.robot`

`all_keywords.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SomeLibrary.py
Resource    basic_keywords.robot
Resource    advanced_keywords_1.robot
Resource    more_advanced_keywords_1.robot
Resource    advanced_keywords_2.robot
```

`more_advanced_keywords_1.robot`:

```
# No Import of basic_keywords.robot here!!!
*** Keywords ***
My More Advanced Keyword
    Advanced Keyword   # from advanced_keywords.robot
    Basic Keyword      # from basic_keywords.robot
```

Import in test suites:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource   all_keywords.robot
```

Benefits:

- This works at execution.
- With the same line in any of the test suites, we have access to all keywords.
- We do not need to import the necessary keywords in each of the advanced keywords files, which would lead to double imports.

Drawbacks:

- Autocompletion etc. is not supported because `advanced_keywords.robot` does not know about `basic_keywords.robot`.
- Imports many (often not used) keywords in test suites, slows down performance (?)

## Proposal 2: Reference `basic_keywords`... in `advanced_keywords`

Proposed by @Todor

`advanced_keywords.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    basic_keywords.robot
*** Keywords ***
Advanced Keyword
    Basic Keyword      # from basic_keywords.robot
```

`more_advanced_keywords_1.robot`:

```
Resource    advanced_keywords.robot
# basic_keywords is imported here by advanced_keywords.robot
*** Keywords ***
My More Advanced Keyword
    Advanced Keyword   # from advanced_keywords.robot
    Basic Keyword      # from basic_keywords.robot
```

Double imports are handled by Robot Framework.

Import in test suites:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource   more_advanced_keywords_1.robot
Resource   advanced_keywords_2.robot
```

Benefits:

- This works at execution
- Auto completion etc. is supported as the IDE knows where the `Advaned Keyword` is defined
- Better control on which keywords are available, faster

Drawbacks:

- You have to explicitly decide / import which `advanced_keywords` you use in a test suite.

Double instantiations of the library can be prevented by `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'` in `SomeLibrary.py`, see [Robot Framework makes two instances from the class instead of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637902/robot-framework-makes-two-instances-from-the-class-instead-of-one) and the [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope)

## Other Proposals?

There are benefits and drawbacks to both proposals. Any recommendations? What structure would you propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At what level does the resolving not work?

Judging from common sense (and personal experience with PyCharm), in suites that import just `basic.robot`, the keywords from `more_advanced_keywords_1.robot` **will be** resolvable - they are indirectly imported through `basic`, and thus in the current context.

When editing `more_advanced_keywords_1`, I don't think there is an IDE which will resolve keywords from `advanced_keywords_1` or `basic`. The reason is that the current file does not have access to them in isolation.

In one usage context (suite A), the consumer may have imported both this file (more_advanced_keywords_1) and another (advanced_keywords_1) and have access to the latter's keywords; but in another context (suite B), the consumer may have imported just more_advanced_keywords_1.
So what would hapen in B, if `more_advanced_keywords_1` was referencing a keyword from `advanced_keywords_1`? It would fail at runtime, as the keyword is not defined (accessible) at this point.
This is the same reason an IDE doesn't resolve the keywords defined in `advanced_keywords_1` or `basic` when editing `more_advanced_keywords_1` - it has no access to them in the current context.

You have two options:

- Bite the bullet and not have IDE resolving in the deeper keyword files; it still will work in the suites, so that's something bearable.
- Go with double imports - `basic` imports `advanced_keywords_1`, and `advanced_keywords_1` imports `basic`; it may sound scary or wrong, but Robot Framework (actually py) manages it just fine. Even circular imports are not causing issues (a imports b, and b imports a).

In the past I had a structure just like yours - a master keyword file, importing in itself 20+ 2nd level resource files, some of them importing 3rd level. I've used the double import and did not run into issues (the only req - no keyword names conflicts).
*Since then I moved to more broken-down structure - no master file, the suites import only the resources they need. The reason - lighter and faster initial loading, and mainly - I was sick of having 1000+ keywords constantly available in the current namespace - e.g. present in the autosuggestion :)*

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I see your point that double imports generally work. But if `basic_keywords` accesses `SomeLibrary.py`, you will generate multiple instances of this library, right? Which can be problematic, for example when accessing a serial connection to a target which can be opened only once. Of course there are workarounds in Python for this (global variables), but still...

Comment: Actually - no, it will generate only one (just tested it) - try it yourself to be sure. What is important - but not directly related to this situation - is the declared [ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope) - this setting controls when/how many times the library itself will be initialized. With `GLOBAL` that is going to be once per run, `TEST SUITE` - on every suite start. Yet this setting is in control (and does it thing) regardless of the import structure. So once again - shouldn't be a problem, try it yourself.

Comment: Actually v2 - scratch that, even `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE` shouldn't mess anything up - the cases and suites in RF are executed in serial, so even if the scope is case or suite, the lib - and the connection will be instantiated only one at a time; if it closes the connection properly (in a destructor, for instance), then there should be no issues.

Comment: In any case a library can always be imported multiple time with a [custom name](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-custom-name-to-test-library): `Library  SomeLibrary  WITH NAME  SomeLibrary2`

Comment: [ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope) was the nessary hint, thank you very much @Todor! I refactor the code s.t. `basic_keywords` will reference the library and `advanced_keyword` will import `basic_keywords`. When setting `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE` explicitly to `'GLOBAL'` I can simply use the keywords in all suites and do not need to explicitly close the connection after a test case etc.

Comment: Side note about library scope: If not set explicitly to `'GLOBAL'`, the library was instantiated multiple times when using multiple nested suites (folders). When set explicitly to `'GLOBAL'`, everything worked without explicitly closing the connection in the library (RobotFramework 3.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

This is issue related with PyCharm IDE, I made an example with RED Robot Editor which handles inherited resources correctly:

```
project structure:
  res/basic.robot contains basic kw
  res/advanced.robot imports basic.robot -> all kws from basic are avaliable and validated
  res/even_more_adv.robot imports advanced.robot -> all kw from advanced + all kw from basic
  main_testsuite.robot imports res/even_more_adv.robot -> all kw from even_more + advanced + basic resources are visible
```

I am pretty sure that RIDE will handle such cases as well although I do not have it installed.

Comment: Your import structure is reversed comparing to OP's - you are importing basic.robot in advanced.robot, while (s)he imports advanced in basic, his suites import just basic then on. In your case (almost) every IDE or plugin for it will resolve succesfully, because it is trivial.

Comment: Thanks. As @Todor mentioned, your proposal would work also in PyCharm. But if you have advanced_2.robot, it would need to import basic.robot again. Which is possible but leads to double imports and I was wondering if there is a way around it (without putting just everything into one huge .robot)

Comment: @Todor - ok,I get it - did not suspect this to work it but I was wrong. In RED,user can use generated keyword docs (robot libdoc module) to autocomplate and validate, this works for libs only but we were evaluating if not to allow this for resource files as well (with and without explicit import in settings section).

Comment: I myself am hardcore pycharm fan (for good or bad... :) but admire what you're doing with RED, and thus helping RF adoption and usage; keep it up! As for the feature you're evaluating - it does sound helpful; I hope when there's no explicit import, the plugin will resolve in the present chain of upstream imports only - e.g. won't try to outsmart the user and present kws not available in the current context.

Comment: Hiding dependencies like in OP example may be convenient on the short run but later on it can create a nightmare to maintain a test library monolith (tests only works with all imports,no possible to validate KW offline, fragility of KW change). Right now in RED user can add KW from non imported resources/libs but RED will add explicit import in settings of current test suite. One place of quasi implicit import is a case when resources are added to python_path (there is an import of file which may not exist in test repo) which I am not fan of that.

Comment: I don't understand OP's design intent the same way you do - for me the purpose is to have a single import in every suite, which will help users get into his framework. "Just import the basic_keywords and you'll have access to all available keywords". The only downside is cross-resource references, but that is solvable with double/circular imports. I also don't agree with you this approach adds extra keyword fragility - it's a design property, and this is dependency management - and management strategy of full exposure ...

Comment: I'm not saying OP's plan is the best architecture - but it's a good enough one. I employed similar for 1.5 years, and moved from it mainly because of getting tired of it (really! :) and separation of the business domains in the SUT (long story, don't ask :). I had minimal issues with it; and once I decided to refactor out of it to explicit and functionality-specific imports, it took not that much time (2-3 mandays) - and the scale was quite big. My point is - this approach is not a dead-end, RF is forgiving when refactoring is needed.